# Create a photo post with multiple photos on Tumblr with php via API

Tags: php, api, tumblr, photos

I managed to create posts on Tumblr via the API using php but I still struggle with having multiple images in a post. The API says that you can create an array as the data parameter: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#blog-submissions but I'm not sure how the description shall be interpreted "One or more image files (submit multiple times to create a slide show)". What does it mean: "submit multiple times"?

So my code to create a photo post with one photo is the following

```
$parameters = array( );
$parameters['type'] = "photo";
$parameters['title'] = $title;
$parameters['caption'] = $caption;
$parameters['date'] = $date;
$parameters['data'] = file_get_contents( '/path/to/file.jpg' );

$post = $tum_oauth->post($post_URI,$parameters);
```

While using the code available through this website: http://techslides.com/tumblr-api-example-using-oauth-and-php
This works fine.

Since the API says that you can use an array for the data parameter, I tried the following to upload multiple photos:

```
$parameters = array( );
$parameters['type'] = "photo";
$parameters['title'] = $title;
$parameters['caption'] = $caption;
$parameters['date'] = $date;
$parameters['data'] = array( file_get_contents( 'path/to/file1.jpg' ), file_get_contents( 'path/to/file2.jpg' ) );

$post = $tum_oauth->post($post_URI,$parameters);
```

Then I get this error message:

> object(stdClass)#48 (2) { ["meta"]=> object(stdClass)#49 (2) {
>   ["status"]=> int(401) ["msg"]=> string(14) "Not Authorized" }
>   ["response"]=> array(0) { } }

I don't think it has something to do with the authorization since it works when I use only one photo. The size of the images are 1.3MB and 0.9MB - the API says there is a limit of 10MB for the URL-encoded binary.

Here I found a "working example" but the way multiple photos are passed here doesn't work for me: https://gist.github.com/codingjester/1649885

Any ideas of what I need to change to get this working?

Comment: try : Photoset works only with relative path to images… (photo is any path).

Comment: I've faced a similar problem, but at the end I've understand that the data I was sending to tumblr was too big, infact, once you get the file contents of the GIFs, you are urlencoding them, resulting in a string 4 time larger than the bytes of the sum of images. so posting a 4Mb photoset results in a 16Mb of string to send to tumblr (which returns an error).